# Открыть попап окно при клике по ссылке на другой странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Есть задачка, а решение не могу найти.

Нужно при клике по ссылке на одной странице, чтобы произошел переход на другую страницу и чтобы открылось нужное попап окно.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Заранее очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к URL-адресу второй страницы хэш `#somehash` или параметр `?someparameter`.
На второй странице реализуйте логику проверки URL-адреса:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //для хэша
  if (window.location.hash === '#somehash') {
    //логика показа нужного попап окна
  }

  //или для параметра
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('someparameter') > 0) {
    //логика показа нужного попап окна
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот простенький пример...

```js
function show(state){
  document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;   
 document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;    
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf8'>
<title>Всплывающее окно на javascript</title>
<style type="text/css">
 
 #wrap{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.725);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 
 #window{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
 }
 
 .close{
  margin-left: 364px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>   
    <div onclick="show('none')" id="wrap"></div>
    <div id="window">
    <img class="close" onclick="show('none')">
    <img  style="margin: 20px 0 0 50px;" src="https://pp.userapi.com/c618326/v618326937/1e1c2/BzcvL1m7NKQ.jpg">
    </div>

    <center><button class="myButton" onclick="show('block')">Показать окно</button></center> 
  
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Где переход на новую страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Если на Тильде, добавь блок html внизу страницы и пиши этот код:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hash !== "") {
    document.write("<a href='" + window.location.hash + "' style='display:none'></a>");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").click();
        }, 500);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]